# Bewildered by Enumerable Min and Max extension methods behavior with uninitialized nullable types

Tags: c#, linq, max, nullable, min

could someone shed some light (or freely speculate) why the Linq Min and Max extension methods behave the way they do when dealing with uninitialized nullable types ?

Perhaps the easiest way is show what I have observed :

```
int? a = null;
int? b = 1;

Nullable.Compare(a, b);                            // -1, indicating null is smaller then 1
new int?[] { null, 1 }.OrderBy(x => x).First();    // null, null smaller then 1

new[] { 0, 1 }.Min();                              // 0 as expected

new int[] { }.Min();                               // invalidoperator exception as expected
```

So far so good, but then ...

```
new int?[] { null, 1 }.Max();                       // 1 as expected
new int?[] { null, 1 }.Min();                       // 1 ?????, why not null ?

new int?[] { null, null }.Min();                    // null, why null now and not above ?

new int?[] { }.Min();                               // null, and no exception ???
```

I admit, I don't particularly care for Nullable types in the first place, but that's another story :-)

I do remain curious though about why it is implemented this way...

Cheers,
Bart

Answer (score 2):

You can decompile the Nullable source code, which results in this definition:

```
    public static int Compare<T>(Nullable<T> n1, Nullable<T> n2) where T : struct
    {
        if (n1.HasValue) {
            if (n2.HasValue) return Comparer<T>.Default.Compare(n1.value, n2.value);
            return 1;
        }
        if (n2.HasValue) return -1;
            return 0;
    }
```

It looks like the nullable.compare method intentionally returns a -1 in the case of n1 being null and n2 having a value.

Likewise you can decompile the linq source code, which results in this definition:

```
    public static int? Min(this IEnumerable<int?> source) {
        if (source == null) throw Error.ArgumentNull("source");
        int? value = null;
        foreach (int? x in source) {
            if (value == null || x < value)
                value = x;
        }
        return value;
    }
```

The iteration over the source object checks if the value is null, and if it is, assigns the x to value*. It's just the default implementation of linq to return a number as the min value during a comparison against null.

As to the question *why* it does that, I assume it's because null represents the absence of a value rather than an integral value, and they (the guys who wrote linq) disagreed with the way comparable was originally built. They probably found no normal execution path where null would be considered the best answer to "what is the minimum **value** of this list of nulls and ints".

Comment: Thank you C., but my question is more about the inconsistency of their choices. The "linq guys" that gave us Min and Max, also wrote OrderBy, which *does* (just like Nullable.Compare) choose to order a valueless nullable value before one that has value. What I have found so far it is only Min and Max that do not respect that ordering, and then even go so far as breaking their own rule that suddenly it is ok to use Min or Max on empty sequences, because the type is nullable, while every other empty sequence will generate an exception.

Comment: The reason I provided you with the compare syntax for nullable types is because according to the [msdn entry for linq's orderby](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534966%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), it uses the default comparer for the type (which is a nullable<T>). So what I provided above gives you the reason, in code, as to why you are getting different values when comparing the output of the two functions.